# Fire Walkers critical hit

Tags: diablo-iii

My Fire Walkers burn the ground I walk on, dealing 100$ weapon damage to enemies within a radius. Can the boots do critical hits? If so, is the crit damage based off your normal damage or the damage the boots do (in this case 100% so it would be the same thing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not own a pair, but there seems to be a consensus online that they cannot crit:

On [Battle.net](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5207751733):

> They don't crit or proc LoH :/

On [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/22r8lz/firewalkers_whats_the_main_appeal/):

> dismiss companion and stand right next to mobs, you will always get the same number. it doesnt crit

You can test it yourself though: equip the boots, and dismiss any other buff/skill/item that damages mobs. Run around and watch the damage, and see if it ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pair of Fire Walkers previously on my [character](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/waffleman71-1137/hero/41397022) (I use Lut Socks now), and I can 100% confirm that the proc on them **DOES NOT** crit at all.